# How do you detect the "destroy" event for a JQuery dialog?

Tags: jquery, dialog

I'm trying to attach javascript to run after a JQuery dialog is destroyed.
I **do not** want to attach the event during declaration of the dialog.

I tried attaching an "on destroy" event in the following manners (none of which worked) -

```
    $('#myDialog'').bind('dialogclose', function (event) {
        //do cool stuff
    });

    $('#myDialog'').bind('dialogdestroy', function (event) {
        //do cool stuff
    });

    $('#myDialog'').bind('destroy', function (event) {
        //do cool stuff
    });
```

The code that destroys the dialog looks like this -

```
$('#myDialog').dialog('destroy');
```

Comment: There is no event triggered for `destroy`. but then, when you think about it.. you don't really need one as it happens right away.. so whatever code you wanted to add.. just put it right after you call destroy.

Comment: Well, ideally I'd like to attach an event on "destroy" or "close". "close" I can attach to.

Comment: Check API documentation for jQuery dialog @ http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/ under Event, there is no event for destroy. jQuery UI does not have that event for you. Of course, you can edit jQuery source if you like to add one.

Answer (score 0):

You can either trigger your custom event directly in destroy method.

Or if you don't want to edit jqueryui file you can implement your own method that would destroy dialog and trigger an event.

```
$.ui.dialog.prototype.myDestroy = function()
{
    this.element.dialog('destroy');
    this.element.trigger('destroyed');
}
```

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/7p6p0mjg/)